# Prove that $\sum_{n\geq 1}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am studying for an admission exam and I find this problems together. I previously showed that $$\sum_{n\geq 1}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$$ converges using root test and showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$.

The next exercise is prove the divergence of $$\sum_{n\geq 1}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)$$ I don`t know if the first result is useful for this.

First, i tried to find a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n<\sqrt[n]{n}-1$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ diverges, but I can´t find any. Then I tried to use the partial sums: $$\sum_{n=1}^{k}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)=(1-1)+(\sqrt{2}-1)+\dots +(\sqrt[k]{k}-1)=1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\dots +\sqrt[k]{k}-k$$ but I didn`t know how to continue. My last attempt was try to prove that the partial series are estrictly increasing and unbounded, but I can´t prove that is unbounded. I am stuck at this point. Thanks for the help, and sorry about my english.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Let us know what you have tried first so that we can better help you.

Comment: Do you remember the result that the sequence $(1+\frac1n)^n$ is increasing and converges to $e$?

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I tried to use comparison but I don´t find another series to compare. I also tried to prove that the series is strictly increasing and unbounded. But I can't find how to prove that it is unbounded.

Comment: @AlejandroPeralta It is advisable to put such attempts in the body of the question.

Comment: Also check out [the quick guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you, I will edit the question whit my attempts.

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite it as $$e^{\ln(n)/n}-e^0$$ and then by the MVT we get $$e^{\ln(n)/n}-e^0=e^{\xi(n)} (\ln(n)/n)$$ with $\xi(n)\in (0,\ln(n)/n)\subset (0,1)$. This allows you to compare to $\sum_n \ln(n)/n$ which diverges.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for the help. Can you explain me the right hand of the ecuation? I can´t see it clearly from MVT.

Comment: @AlejandroPeralta It is the MVT for $f(x)=e^x, b=\ln(n)/n, a=0$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you, I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use a comparison to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)$ diverges.

To start, it is well-known that the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. This is the sequence we will be comparing to.

First, we need to prove that $\frac{1}{x}$ is less than $x^{1/x}-1$ at some $x=k$, and that it stays less. So, we want to find when:

$\frac{1}{x} < x^{1/x}-1$

$1 + \frac{1}{x} < x^{1/x}$

$(1 + \frac{1}{x})^{x} < x$ (both sides are positive as we are only considering $x>0$)

This is obviously true for *some* $x=k$; it is well-known that $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}$ is monotonically increasing and approaches $e$ as $x \to \infty$, and $x$ trivially approaches $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. We can take any $x>e$, say $3$, and this is a point where the terms of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{1/n}-1$ are greater than the terms of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$. They will stay greater as $n \to \infty$, and hence we have that:

$\sum_{n=3}^{k} > \sum_{n=3}^{k} \frac{1}{n}$

and as $k \to \infty$, because the right-hand sum diverges, the left-hand sum will diverge. Adding in the $n=1$ and $n=2$ terms will not impact divergence, and the proof is done.

Sidenote: I'm sorry if my proof was badly worded or not rigorous enough, I am fresh out of a calc 2 class and I do not have that much experience writing formal proofs. Hopefully my meaning is clear. Please suggest any edits if it is not.

Comment: The question is a duplicate. Please take a look at the duplicate and if your answer significantly differs from those given there, post yours there instead.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I've posted my answer there as well.

Comment: @DanielGeyfman ty, your explanation was so clear.